# Validation errors hierarchy design

Tags: c#, oop, validation, class-hierarchy

In our system we have an entity `Product`, which might have various custom properties. Set of properties might differ from product to product, and is stored in a field of type `List<Property>`. Properties are of different types (strings, ints, double) and might have some special characteristics, e.g. they might be multivalued, might be a value of s specific range, a value from the given list etc. Value of the property is always contained in the string field `Value`.

Now my current problem is to implement validation of these properties and I am kind of stuck on what approach to take in part of erpresentation of the validation results. Requirements that I have to satisfy:
    - Results of the validation will be used by other application layers, so the resulting API should be clear and easy to use
    - Each error should have a distinct representation
    - Users of the API should have enough information to understand error specifics (for example for range errors they should be provided with minimal possible value, maximal possible value and actual value)

Here are the approaches I have considered so far:

1. *Classes hierarchy.* There is one base abstract class `ValidationError`, and each specific error will be reflected in a inherited class. If error has any specifics, corresponding class will have necessary fields to store all the information. Example:

   ```
   public abstract class ValidationError
   {
       // common fields and methods, if any
   }

   public class IncorrectFormatValidationError : ValidationError
   {
       // just empty class, nothing to add here
   }

   public class RangeValidationError : ValidationError
   {
       public object MinValue { get; set; }

       public object MaxValue { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   This approach seems to be rather redundant to me because of variety of actually empty classes. Furthermore usage of such a API does not seem to be right (`if (typeof(error) == typeof(RangeValidationError))` - nonsense!). However this is the first thing that came to my mind.
2. *Errors enumeration and, where necessary, classes hierarchy.* All errors are represented with enumeration. There is one class `ValidationError` that is used in most cases, and when additional info is necessary for specific error, the inheritor is created, basically the same way as in the first approach. Example:

   ```
   public enum ValidationErrors
   {
       IncorrectFormat,
       ValueNotWithinRange,
       ...
   }

   public class ValidationError
   {
       public ValidationErrors ErrorType { get; set; } 

       public ValidationError(ValidationErrors type)
       {
           this.ErrorType = type;
           ...
       }

       // common fields and methods, if any
   }

   public class RangeValidationError : ValidationError
   {
       public object MinValue { get; set; }

       public object MaxValue { get; set; }

       public RangeValidationError(object minValue, object maxValue) :
           base(ValidationErrors.ValueNotWithinRange)
       {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   This approach looks much better, however there are drawbacks as well. The biggest one is that we as a API users cannot be guaranteed that when we have the error of type say `ValueNotWithinRange`, we are dealing with class of type `RangeValidationError`, and if we are not - how do we handle it? Idially I would like to have some design-level feature that would prevent even existing of such situations, since I am not the onyl one who develops the API. Another issue with this approach is that if most errors will in the end require some additional info, we'll eventually end up with the same aprroach number 1.

Anyone has any thoughts to share on these two approaches or suggest a better one? I will highly appreciate any response. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a good idea to take a step back and rethink the whole "multiple classes representing validation *errors*" approach, because it's almost guaranteed that you already have a hierarchy of *validators*.

Any validation error could be perfectly specified given:

1. The validator that failed to accept the value of a property
2. The name of the property
3. The value that failed to validate

Any further information (e.g. limits of a range, a regular expression that did not match) is already present on the the validator instance and can be accessed through that.

So what about having just one validation error class that looks like this:

```
public sealed class ValidationError
{
    public Validator Validator { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public object AttemptedValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, you avoid hierarchy duplication this way, but you also introduce extra downcasting of abstract Validator. I propose changing Validator into a type parameter.

Comment: @Basilevs: The downcasting would be necessary anyway (even in a `ValidationError` hierarchy) if you need to access members not present on the hierarchy root (e.g. the `Min` and `Max` properties). The only other way is to build a facility to access property values dynamically at runtime, which is the moral equivalent of using reflection and has the same basic issue: loss of type safety.

Comment: @Jon, thanks for the response. No, I do not have validators so far. All validation is done in several BL-level methods. However maybe it's worth thinking about their introduction? But if so, we are facing the same problem as for the errors (which is described in the question), aren't we?

Comment: @Jon, consider exception catching - in this case downcasting is done automatically in a safe way. To have all type information after this single downcasting would be nicer then perfoming downcasting  again.

Comment: @Andrei: Yes, the same problems indeed; however, modeling the validators well is much more useful than modeling the validation errors (and it also automatically takes care of the errors as well). I 'd go with the first approach there.

Comment: @Andrei, Jon propose not to have Error hierarchy at all - only Validators. Those are good idea anyway - if validation and error reporting procedures can share common parameters duplicating them smells bad.

Comment: @Basilevs: Downcasting does not pose a safety problem, but a maintenance problem because you now have a giant type switch somewhere. You cannot get around this no matter what method you pick to perform the downcast.

Comment: @Jon, any thoughts on how to deal with the type safety problem?

Comment: @Andrei: Type safety problems only exist if you make a *dynamic* API to fetch validator (or error, it's the same thing) parameters, or if you have bugs. Which problem exactly do you have in mind? Might be better to edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @Jon, actually I take it back, it only concerns the second approach, and you have mentioned that you'd choose the first one. Thanks again, I will try it and see if everything worked out well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at something like [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/). It's lightweight, intuitive and covers a lot of validation scenarios.

If you're not satisfied with the validation results used by FluentValidation, you can always wrap them in your own custom validation error classes. At least you'll get a a lot of basic functionality for free.